# how do i change color on the switch in both android and ios?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms

I need to be able to change the color of the switch both on `android` and `ios` in `xamarin.forms` since one is green and the other black, but the main color of the app is yellow `#FED000`, how can I do?

Comment: I Have resolve on android, I have change color theme, but iOS not have resolve

Comment: what do you mean about `OnColor` on iOS? Which part didn't you implement?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom renderer:

In your Forms Solution:

```
public class CustomSwitch : Switch
{
}
```

Then, in your iOS Solution:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomSwitch), typeof(CustomSwitchRenderer))]

namespace yourNameSpace
{
    public class CustomSwitchRenderer : SwitchRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Switch> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged (e);

            if (Control != null) 
            {
                 //change color
                Control.OnTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB (204, 153, 255);
            }
         }
    }
}
```

However, if you want to change all switch in application, you can simply:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    // switch
    UISwitch.Appearance.OnTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(0,0,0);


    return base.FinishedLaunching (app, options);
}
```